# Fetching .kmz files from local disk and importing them into Google Earth via API

Tags: google-earth, google-earth-plugin, collada, kmz

I need to import 3D models of each building in New York City into the Google Earth API.  I fetched their .kmz files using google.earth.fetchKml.  Since this command uses the URL of the kmz files and the number of files to imported is a lot it is very slow.

Is there any way I can fetch these files from my local disk?

Are there other formats I can use instead of .kmz?  For example .dae files?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a local file (non http) url to fetch your KML data.

But you could run a local webserver and use that.

For example, if you have python installed you could go to your directory with your KML files and run "python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000", at which point pointing to http://localhost:8000/myfile.kml would load them up.

That said you should also note that the terms of use for the plugin require your site be publicly available, amongst other things - so hopefully you are only using this setup for local testing :)